# Anglicisme : des machines exascale ou des machines exascales ?

Tags: adjectifs, accord, anglicismes

[Exascale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exascale_computing) est un anglicisme technique désignant la prochaine génération de supercalculateurs capable d'effectuer 10^18 opérations à virgule flottante par seconde.

Ma question est la suivante, dans le cas d'un anglicisme technique de ce type : utilisé en tant qu'adjectif, le pluriel prend-il un "s" ?

Autrement dit, dois-je écrire "des machines exascale" ou "des machines exascales" ?

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que les adjectifs empruntés à d'autres langues sont généralement *invariables*, ce qui donne **des machines exascale**.

([une source](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/le-pluriel-des-emprunts-254.php), à confirmer éventuellement, car je ne connais pas ce site)

Answer (score 3):

Plutôt que l'anglicisme, on trouve dans la littérature les termes "supercalculateur exaflopique" ou "super ordinateur de classe Exascale". En disant "des machines de classe Exascale", ton adjectif sera forcément au singulier, ce qui règle ton problème.

Answer (score 1):

Dans d'autres contextes il est possible de traduire *mega-* ou *giga-* par *géant* ou *gros* (par exemple *projet géant* pour *megaproject*).

Mais ici je ne vois pas pourquoi le français ne peut pas traiter *exa-* comme un préfixe, à l'instar de l'anglais.