# Traduction de « exascale supercomputer/supercomputing »

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie

On a fait [référence](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13641) à « *exascale* » avec un *supercalculateur* ([Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=SUPERCOMPUTER), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8386534)) dans le contexte du *calcul intensif* ([FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=calcul%20intensif&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=SUPERCOMPUTING&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0)). Le préfixe [*exa-*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&srchtxt=EXA) (*10 à la dix-huitième puissance*) est aussi utilisé en français; on a l'[*exabit*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8357747) (*un milliard de milliard de bits*; 1000 pétabits) et l'[*exbioctet/exaoctet*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&srchtxt=EXABYTE) (2<sup>60</sup> octets). Enfin on a l'*échelle* ([*scale*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=scale&comencsrch.x=8&comencsrch.y=9); voir [aussi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4292)).

Alors comment traduit-on:

> *Exascale (super)computing
>  Exascale (super)computer(s)*

...avec une attention particulière à l'emploi des prépositions/articles le cas échéant, ainsi qu'à l'assemblage entre le préfixe et le mot « échelle » ? La réponse complète permettrait de dire correctement « je m'intéresse » en y ajoutant indistinctement l'une ou l'autre des deux réponses sans modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me say I am not sure if an official specific french word has been made for that. French tends to keep a lot of English words when it comes to computer science. However, I found in this article ( [un premier superordinater avant 2020](http://pro.01net.com/editorial/546646/un-premier-superordinateur-exascale-avant-2020/) ) the terms : "super ordinateur de classe Exascale", ou encore "ordinateur exaflopique". Pas de traduction littérale de "scale" en échelle, donc.

Pour conclure, je dirais : "je m'intéresse aux supercalculateurs exaflopiques".

Comment: Merci! Le terme anglais appliqué à la « classe », bien utile! Aussi exa+flops, la construction avec les opérations à virgule flottante par seconde en adjectif, excellent; je pensais qu'échelle serait requis mais pas nécessairement. Quant à l'informatique de pointe, je ne sais pas si c'est une tendance [moderne](http://publications.gc.ca/collections/collection_2014/tpsgc-pwgsc/S52-2-184-1.pdf); personnellement ce n'est pas mon expérience mais bon.